# Distributive law of addition over maximum?

Tags: arithmetic

I learned from this article that:

> For real numbers, addition distributes over the maximum operation, and also over the minimum operation:
> $a+\max(b, c)=\max(a+b, a+c)$ and $a+\min(b, c)=min(a+b, a+c)$

I wonder if the following distributive law holds?

$\max(a, b)+\max(c, d)=\max(\max(a, b)+c, \max(a, b)+d)$ and $\min(a, b)+\min(c, d)=\min(\min(a, b)+c, \min(a, b)+d)$

I just replace `a` with $max(a, b)$.

I ask this question because I cannot get my head around while reading this paper: [The Generalized Distributive Law](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/1541/1/AJIieeetit00.pdf), especially on the Viterbi part.

Comment: it holds for every real number $a$ so it must also hold for $\text{max}(a,b)$ too, since $\text{max}(a,b)$ also a real number.

Comment: I wonder if that can prove the optimality of Viterbi decoding? @Azlif